# Unknown margin under li elements when float left

Tags: html, css

i have made a simple navbar with css but some how it is showing margin at the botton of my `<li>` tags.Here the picture.And when i remove the float property the margin under the `<li>` disappears.

[image]

And here is the css.

```
nav{
    background:#333;
}
nav ul{
    display:inline-block;
}
nav ul li{
    display:inline;
    float:left;
    list-style:none;
}
nav ul li a{
    color:#fff;
    padding:15px;
    display:block;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-weight:600;
    font-size:16px;
}
```

Comment: Can you post a Fiddle please?

Comment: Remove `display: inline` as it is useless with `float:left` and add `height:100%`.

Comment: Having display:inline and float:left on your LI is a bit redundant, yeah?

Can you post a jsfiddle of the whole thing?

Comment: in jsfiddle the results are totally different http://jsfiddle.net/JB4Wx/

Comment: @BramVanroy did not work.

Comment: My guess: It's the descender height from the `inline-block` on the `ul`. If you are using `inline-block` there to stop the element from collapsing around the floats, then use `overflow: hidden` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove `display:inline-block;` from the `nav ul` and use `display:inline-block;` for the `nav ul li` with no `float` i.e.

```
nav{
    background:#333;
}
nav ul li{
    display:inline-block;
    list-style:none;
}
nav ul li a{
    color:#fff;
    padding:15px;
    display:block;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-weight:600;
    font-size:16px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Add inline-block to li**

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/8wSCX/)**

**CSS**

```
nav ul li{
    display:inline-block;
    list-style:none;
}
```